# Does GitLab CE audit log clone / pull requests?

Tags: gitlab

I’m investigating alternatives in my projects for my team (20+ developers). i want something that can be run on server and has auditing (check) that logs

```
Push
Pull
Clone of projects
```

I can’t find anything in the docs about this for GitLab community

Does anyone here know if these features are supported? or any plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the level of logging you're requesting has not been implemented into GitLabs, but [there are plans in place](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/474) to implement them, though there is currently no estimated time of arrival.

Comment: In the current version , this level of logging is not implemented ?

Comment: That's correct. You can see what is currently logged [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_events.html). For future reference, I am able to find this information with a single Google search. I would suggest doing your own research.

Answer (score 0):

Audit events are richer now, with [GitLab 14.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/09/22/gitlab-14-3-released/#audit-events-for-merge-request-approval-setting-changes) (September 2021)

> ### Audit events for merge request approval setting changes
>
> Audit events are now created if changes are made to the [merge request approval settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/settings.html)
> in a project. You can now see if a change is made to the following policies:
>
> - Requiring user password for approvals.
> - Allowing modifying merge request approvals in a merge request.
> - Needing to get new approvals when a new commit is added to a merge request.
>
> You can now be confident that once you configure approval settings, you can quickly see
> if they are changed. This is a great way to show auditors that controls were put in place
> and have not been removed or modified.
>
> Thanks to [Adrien Gooris](https://gitlab.com/adrien.gooris) from [Michelin](https://www.michelin.com/en/) for this contribution!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_3/mr_settings_audit_events.png -- Audit events for merge request approval setting changes]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_events.html#project-events) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/336211).

---

And [GitLab 15.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/07/22/gitlab-15-2-released/#audit-events-for-group-level-merge-request-settings) (July 2022) adds (for non-CE only)

> ### Audit events for group-level merge request settings
>
> GitLab now records additional audit events when changes are made to group-level merge request settings. These are in addition to project
> audit events that record changes to the same settings on projects. Specifically, audit events are now created when changes are made to groups to:
>
> - Prevent approval by author
> - Prevent approvals by users who add commits
> - Prevent editing approval rules in projects and merge requests.
> - Require user password to approve
> - Remove all approvals when commits are added to the source branch
>
> These audit events can help you know that the settings and default configurations for your group-level merge request settings have been put in place correctly and that they have not been changed.
> This is especially important because these group-level settings
> will cascade down to child projects.
> Governance and visibility over these changes will help you strengthen separation of duties and further simplify audits.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_2/manage-group-level-approval-audit-events.png -- Audit events for group-level merge request settings]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_events.html#group-events) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/356152).

---

[GitLab 15.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/07/22/gitlab-15-2-released/#streaming-audit-events-for-project-forks) (July 2022) also propose to audit a special kind of clone: forks.
But only for GitLab Ultimate, so again, not CE.

> ### Streaming audit events for project forks
>
> You can now monitor the project forking inside your groups with new audit events that are recorded whenever
> a project is forked. This includes information such as:
>
> - The user name of the user that forked the project.
> - The timestamp of when the project was forked.
> - Details of the forked project.
>
> This gives you visibility on where your projects and source code are being copied to, and by
> whom, so that you can take action if needed.
>
> These events potentially generate a high volume of data, so they are only available as
> [streaming audit events](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_event_streaming.html).
>
> Thank you [Linjie Zhang](https://gitlab.com/zhanglinjie) for this contribution!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_event_streaming.html#audit-event-streaming-on-project-fork-actions) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/367241).